<Select> + PHP / SQL
Tengo un <select> que por default tiene las siguientes opciones:

Estas mismas al ser seleccionada por el usuario, las guarda y se mandan a la base de datos a la columna de perfil.

Cada <option> esta asociada al id único del usuario que se relaciona con la columna llamada emp_code, lo que se haya seleccionado la muestra en el <select> una vez insertada en la base de datos, pero como pueden notar debido al código me está mostrando la opción repetida porque está entrando en esta condición:
// Dependiendo la opcion ya seleccionada mostrara el desglose
if ($opcion == 'Sindicalizado') {
    echo "<option value='Empleado'>Empleado</option>";
} else {
    echo "<option value='Sindicalizado'>Sindicalizado</option>";
}


Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que si ya hay resultados mostrados en el <select> quisiera que mostrara la otra opción, esto con la finalidad de que el usuario pueda generar el cambio de perfil, pero no consigo hacerlo; debería quedar algo así el <select> esto dependiendo que opción haya mandado a la base de datos.
El código que tengo hasta ahorita es este:
<div class="col">
    <input type="hidden" name="codigoEmpleado" value="<?php echo $_row_empleado['emp_code']; ?>">
    <p>Perfil: </p>

    <?php
    // Obtener la opción seleccionada para el usuario actual desde la base de datos
    $opcion_seleccionada = isset($_POST['perfil']) ? $_POST['perfil'] : '';
    $sql_nomina = "SELECT * FROM [BDG_CHECADORES_BITACORA].[dbo].[tabla_relacion_nomina] WHERE emp_code = '" . $_row_empleado['emp_code'] . "'";
    $result = sqlsrv_query($con, $sql_nomina);

    // Si no hay datos en la tabla SQL, se definen opciones predeterminadas
    $opciones_predeterminadas = array("Sindicalizado", "Empleado");

    if (sqlsrv_has_rows($result)) {
        // Si hay datos en la tabla SQL, selecciona la ingresada
        echo "<select class='form-select' name='perfil' id='perfil'>";
        while ($_row_nomina = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
            $opcion = $_row_nomina['perfil'];
            $selected = ($opcion == $opcion_seleccionada) ? 'selected' : '';

            echo "<option value='$opcion' $selected>$opcion</option>";

            // Dependiendo la opcion ya seleccionada mostrara el desglose
            if ($opcion == 'Sindicalizado') {
                echo "<option value='Empleado'>Empleado</option>";
            } else {
                echo "<option value='Sindicalizado'>Sindicalizado</option>";
            }
        }
        echo "</select>";
    } else {
        // Si no hay datos en la tabla SQL, generar opciones predeterminadas
        echo "<select class='form-select' name='perfil' id='perfil'>";
        echo "<option hidden>Selecciona una opción</option>";
        foreach ($opciones_predeterminadas as $opcion) {
            echo "<option value='$opcion'>$opcion</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
    }

    ?>
</div>

Espero haber sido clara, muchas gracias por cualquier aportación.

Si ya estas trayendo las opciones de la base de datos, porque las vuelves a poner manualmente debajo?

Porque en la base de datos solo se inserta la opción seleccionada por el usuario, como tal por default si el selecciona sindicalizado debería mostrar esa opción ya seleccionada pero al desplegar debería mostrar la opción de empleado también.

No entiendo muy bien la lógica que sigues en tu código. ¿Las opciones posibles son muchas? ¿Están en alguna tabla en la base de datos? ¿No sería mejor seleccionarlas en una consulta aparte, en caso de estar en una tabla y luego verificar cuál es la del registro para marcar esa como selected? Si las opciones posibles no están en una tabla aparte, entonces puedes crear un array con ellas, pero lo lógico es que existieran en una tabla en tu capa de datos.

Formularé mejor mi pregunta, creo que no fui muy específica con lo que quisiera obtener.

Ya formulé nuevamente la pregunta.

Tu problema radica en que esta mal planteado de entrada. Ese select, como el 99% de los selects y las cosas de una app, debe venir de una tabla en la db, y dicha tabla es la que dicta que se muestra y que no, y en lugar de guardar el nombre, en la otra tabla guardas el id de relacion. Y con eso, se solucionan todos estos problemas, y varios problema mas que vas a tenre a futuro usando el metodo que estas usando ahora...

¿Entonces si entendí bien, me sugieren que estas opciones vengan establecidas en una tabla de la base de datos que ocupo?

si, basicamente te estamos sugiriendo que lo hagas bien, para evitarte problemas a futuro.

Tu problema es mas sencillo de lo que creía.
estas sobreescribiendo las opciones dentro del While, como tu mismo lo indicas.
// Dependiendo la opcion ya seleccionada mostrara el desglose
if ($opcion == 'Sindicalizado') {
echo "<option value='Empleado'>Empleado</option>";
} else {
echo "<option value='Sindicalizado'>Sindicalizado</option>";
}

Este bloque de código es el que estas sobreescribiendo en cada ciclo del while, eliminalo y debería bastar.
El detalle es que en tu while ya estas definiendo que debe mostrar todas las opciones, la única diferencia es que el selected será el que cumpla la condición,  y tu mismo lo tienes definido en tu código como:
$selected = ($opcion == $opcion_seleccionada) ? 'selected' : '';

O sea todas las opciones se mostraran pero solo sera selected la opción que cumple la condición de lo contrario mostrara ''.

Tu base de datos esta mal diseñada, lo que deberias hacer es que tu campo perfil sea una llave foranea de una tabla que tenga todos tus perfiles, o si estas usando perfiles estaticos (no se agragaran mas tipos) puedes usar enum:
public enum perfil:int{
   EMPLEADO = 1,
   SINDICALIZADO = 2
}

teniendo el enum tu solo cargas en tu <select> los enums de perfil, y por defecto dejas seleccionado el perfil que recuperes de la base de datos: <option selected>
